# Hot Towel - Knockout binding not updating observablearray

Tags: knockout.js, durandal, hottowel, ko.observablearray

I am creating a SPA project using Hot Towel template.
I have list view which shows a list of items, and when an item is clicked on, it will go to the detail view.

```
router.mapRoute('details/:module/:id', 'viewmodels/details', 'Details', false);
```

The URL of the detail screen becomes:

```
https://xxx/test/#/details/news/4
```

My detail screen contains an observable array which is populated using AJAX on the details.js activation method.

```
<button class="btn btn-info"
    data-bind="click: save">
    <i class="icon-save"></i>Save</button>

<form id="myform" data-bind="submit: submitForm">
    <table>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: screenDataArray">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: FieldLabel"></td>
                <td>
                    <input data-bind="value: FieldValue" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

The FieldLable and FieldValue displays no problem, assuming this means the data-bind is indeed correct.

I change the FieldValue and when I click on the Save button:

```
var save = function () {
  ko.utils.arrayForEach(screenDataArray(), function (sd) { alert(sd.FieldName + ":" + sd.FieldValue); });
```

My problem is that FieldValue still contains the original values (not updated).

Now I click on the browser refresh button.

I change the value and click on save.

Now the save function alerts the correct changed values.

I would assume the code chain is exactly the same, but I don't understand why when redirected from the list view it doesn't work, but a refresh would suddenly work.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From the code snippet you posted:

```
var save = function () {
  ko.utils.arrayForEach(screenDataArray(), function (sd) { alert(sd.FieldName + ":" + sd.FieldValue); });
```

It looks like the FieldValue is itself not an observable (which it needs to be for your code to work).  observableArrays will listen for changes like add and remove element (methods called on the observableArray itself), but they don't really know when one of their elements changes.  Thats up to the element itself to do by being an observable.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however it does not explain why when I refresh the screen (i.e. going directly to the details view rather than via the list view), it properly captured the values on the screen.